Conjugacy class size and normal subgroup
Let G be a finite group and let $x \in G$ and let $Cl_G(x)$ denote the conjugacy class of $ x \in G$ . It is known that $|G|=|Cl_G (x)||C_G (x)| $ where $C_G (x)$ is the centralizer of $x$ in G as usual.
I would like to prove the following assertion:
If N is a normal subgroup of a finite group G and if $x \in N$, then $|Cl_N(x)|$ divides $|Cl_G(x)|$
I would appreciate any kind of help

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

I have just edited my question. Thank you.

In the dupe target $n\in N$. Here more generally $x\in G$, as far as I see.

Also the answer in the duplicate seems unnecessarily long. $|{\rm Cl}_G(x)|/|{\rm Cl}_N(x)| = |G:NC_G(x)|$.

Just because of the fact that $C_N(x)=N \cap C_G(x)$. Thank you very much for the answer.

@Kan't thanks for the correction
